# Why is Firebase FCM notifications sent even to the sender of the message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Like in whatsapp if i send a message to others they get notified through push notifications and am not sent that same push notification because am the sender.
In firebase regardless of you being the sender or not, you get the push notifications of the messages that you even sent. How can I be able to send notifications to others excluding me if am the sender?

I am using Firebase Cloud functions to send the push notifications.

Comment: that for sure is a problem wi the way you send notification.

Comment: whooa, cloud function, okay just put a name field(in pojo class) to distinguish whether payload data(received model) has your name on it...not a Firebase Question

Comment: @Rigan: I wrote an answer below on why this works the way it does. But more likely you have some specific code that you'd like to skip the user who it's sending the message for. In that case we can help best if you show the code in your question that is sending the message. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a great explanation on how to get help for code-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "sender" in your question refers to a user of your app, and that you're implementing user-to-users messaging. This typically works by having your app call out to a server, which then uses the FCM API to send the message:

```
+--------+          +------------+          +----------+
| Sender |   --->   | App Server |   --->   | Receiver |
+--------+          +------------+    |     +----------+
                                      |
                                      |     +----------+
                                      +->   | Receiver |
                                            +----------+
```

Firebase Client Messaging has no implicit knowledge of the user that is sending the message. Sending messages **to** devices is a server-side API, that runs with administrative access. It is not running as a specific user, hence can't skip that specific user even if it wanted to.

If you want to skip sending to a specific user, you will need to pass the information about that user *into* the code that calls the FCM API to send the message, and then skip the users ID tokens in there. Say that you're using the Firebase Admin SDK in a Node server to send messages, the code could look like this:

```
var UIDs = ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"];
var TOKENS = { "uid1": "token1", "uid2": "token2", "uid3": "token3" };

function sendMessage(messageText, senderUid) {
  UIDs.forEach(function(recipientUid) {
    if (recipientUid !== senderUid) {       
      var message = {
        notification: {
          title: 'Message from '+senderUid,
          body: messageText
        },
        token: TOKENS[recipientUID
      };

      admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The term *token* in this context refers to a device registration token (sometimes also called an instance id token), which identifies a specific app on a specific device. Such tokens are used to determine where a message is sent to. For more samples of this, see the FCM documentation on sending messages to individual devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices